# compiling proto files at runtime

Tags: c#, dynamic, runtime, protocol-buffers

I'm working a generic protobuf decoder that works as follows:

The user can specify the .proto file at runtime and specify the data file and the program would display the data in the file based on the .proto definition.

To do the above, the most obvious things seems like I would need to interpret the .proto file (or compile it) and then decode the protobuf message using it. Any ideas on how I can proceed on this? Is there a library out there that would help me with this.

As always, any feedback is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Also - if you are interested in combining forces in some way towards the betterment of protobuf on the .NET platform, let me know (my contact info is on my profile)

Comment: I would love to do this in a few months. I'm wrapping up a few large projects at this points so I won't be able to spend much time on this. But after that, I would love to help out - will keep in touch. Thank you for the invite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I keep meaning to write my own parser, but *for now* I just use "protoc" to parse the .proto to a protobuf binary. I then deserialize that using my own protobuf library, giving me a populated object model to work with.

I don't know how far along you are, but you might also be interested in some of the runtime support in protobuf-net v2, which allows on-the-fly mapping of protobuf data to types. Alternatively there's also a fairly re-usable reader implementation that might suit your needs.

If you could work from XML, I include a tool in protobuf-net, "protogen", which does code-gen; but pass in a `-t:xml` and it should transform a .proto into XML for you.

Iirc, "protoc" outputs a protobuf using "descriptor.proto" from the google package.

Comment: Mark, thank you for the helpful pointers. I'll let you know how it goes. I think I've quite a bit to go on now and figure out a strategy. :)